# cadena de conexion con SqlConnectionStringBuilder

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, vb.net, .net

soy nueva en ADO.NET y estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación en 3 Capas,LA CONEXION NO PUEDE ESTAR EN EL CONFIG, por es es necesario que este en una clase dentro de la capa de datos, pero no logro establecer una conexión con la base de datos me sale el error, en este caso es una prueba que estoy haciendo conectando con el servidor local que es mi PC y me aparece este mensaje

System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader: la propiedad Connection no se ha inicializado.'

estoy construyendo la cadena de conexión con el  SqlConnectionStringBuilder

estoy colocando el siguiente código:
CAPA DATOS

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Datos
{
public class Conex
{

    public SqlConnection cadenaconex { get; set; }

    private string cadena()
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder con = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        con.DataSource = @"SVCDES03";
        con.InitialCatalog = "NORTHWND";
        con.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        return con.ToString();
    }


    public SqlConnection Conexcd()
    {

        using (SqlConnection cadenaconex = new SqlConnection(cadena()))
        {

            cadenaconex.Open();
            return cadenaconex;
        }
    }


  }
 }
```

EN OTRA CLASE DE LA CAPA DE DATOS

```
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;


 namespace Datos
 {
 public class D_Consultas
  {

    Conex Conexion = new Conex();

    SqlDataAdapter dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

    string query = @"Select * from NORTHWND.dbo.Cliente";



   public DataTable Consul()
    {

        Conexion.Conexcd();
        command.Connection = Conexion.cadenaconex;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = query;
        SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(dataReader);
        return dt;
    }
```

CAPA DE NEGOCIOS

```
   using Datos;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Negocios
{
 public class B_Logica
  {
    D_Consultas d_Consultas = new D_Consultas();


    DataTable DataTable = new DataTable();

    public DataTable MostrarCliente()
    {
        DataTable = d_Consultas.Consul();
        return DataTable;
    }


     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu error esta acá:

```
using (SqlConnection cadenaconex = new SqlConnection(cadena()))
{
    cadenaconex.Open();
    return cadenaconex;
}
```

Que hace el `using`?

Puedes declara un entorno seguro donde al finalizar, las variables serán descartadas, usando `dispose` (ver [aca](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement))

Por lo tanto, como pusiste un `using` ahi, cadenaconex no tiene nada. Pero nada de nada, porque luego del `return`, se hizo un `dispose` de cadenaconex. Y por lo tanto, la misma quedo vacía.

No veo porque tendrías que usar un `using` en este caso. Si creas una clase conexión, o al usar la misma la pones en un `using`, o te encargas de crear un método que cierre y haga un `dispose` de la conexión.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente el problema lo tienes en tu clase Conex. Dentro del método Conexcd estás utilizando el using, esto lo que hace es un dispose una vez terminada la sentencia. Modifica tu método

```
public SqlConnection Conexcd()
{

    SqlConnection cadenaconex = new SqlConnection(cadena());

    cadenaconex.Open();
    return cadenaconex;

}
```

Y prueba de nuevo. Adicionalmente sería bueno que hicieras otro método para cerrar la conexión, o en tu capa de datos cerrarla al terminar de utilizarla.

Answer (score 0):

lo Solucione así :

```
 public Conex()
        {
            string cadenadeconex = cadena();
            cadenaconex = new SqlConnection(cadenadeconex);

        }

         public void abreconex()
         {
             if (cadenaconex.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
             {
                cadenaconex.Open();

             }

         }

            public void cerrarConex()
            {
                if (cadenaconex.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    cadenaconex.Close();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la respuesta que te sirvio, inclusive si es la tuya!

Comment: Hola, y como acepto la respuesta? @gbianchi

Comment: Hiciste el [tour], pero se ve que no lo leiste, solo lo pasaste de largo ;). Debajo de los votos de cada respuesta, hay un tilde que te permite aceptar la respuesta que soluciono tu problema. Tenelo en cuenta para todas tus preguntas.

Comment: ah Ok , Muchas Gracias!! @gbianchi